# Installing Ruby on Mac OS High Sierra error

Tags: ruby, macos, macos-high-sierra

I've been trying to create a static website using Jekyll static website generator but for using it I have to install ruby using my terminal. But when I run `brew install ruby` I get this message error and I couldn't find a solution yet.

```
Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

Error: ruby: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
 brew install --build-from-source ruby
Please note building from source is unsupported. You will encounter build
failures with some formulae. If you experience any issues please create pull
requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub, Twitter or any other
official channels.
```

Should I install it from source as the error message says ?

Comment: Is upgrading macOS an option? I mean you will have other issues down the line when working with an old version of macOS anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can try install a Ruby Manager with Homebrew. I prefer to use rbenv. There are other options, notably rvm. Choose one and stick to it.

If you choose to use rbenv

`brew install ruby-build rbenv`

Follow the brew caveats in your terminal to add any needed environmental variables.

To list available versions

`rbenv install --list`

Install the one you like

`rbenv install <version number>`

As mentioned in a comment you may run into more issues down the line so if possible upgrade macOS version.